# Neo4j: Slow query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 212 Nodes with 56741 relationships.

Trying to find a relationship from node A to B with a depth of 2 goes on forever until I quit Neo4j. Do I need to tweak anything?

The instance is a c3.large(amazon) with
    ECUs: 7, vCPUs: 2, Memory: 3.75 and 2x16(SSD) storage.

```
START a=node(0), d=node(3) 
MATCH p=a-[r:schedules*2]-d
return p;
```

**Configuration**

```
Java version "1.7.0_51"  
Neo4j version 2.0.1

169K  neostore.nodestore.db
9.0M neostore.propertystore.db
11M  neostore.propertystore.db.arrays
3.1M  neostore.relationshipstore.db

wrapper.java.initmemory=500
wrapper.java.maxmemory=1024  


neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=15M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=30M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=30M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=10M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=30M
```

Comment: I guess you have a moderate quantity of loops... Are you interested in all of those paths?

Comment: I am only interested in paths from A to B, I can use -->(direction), would that help? There are other conditions I need to specify on relationships properties, for example

`r1 = A-->C`
`r2 = C-->B`

I need to specify a condition such as r1.property > r2.property

Comment: Is *2 the correct way to specify depth?

Comment: Adding a direction will definitely help. It'll reduce the amount of traversals a lot.